# Front end Sensitive info

Tags: javascript, security, frontend

I am building my first react app and not sure about front end security. I am making a call to the following third party library: `emailjs.sendForm(serviceID, templateID, templateParams, userID);`
The userId field is sensitive information. I make the following call on my onSubmit handler. I am wondering if I need to secure this information somehow? Also, is there a way for me to check if a user can somehow see this information my inspecting and finding the code in the method somehow?

```
emailjs
          .sendForm(
            "gmail",
            "client-email",
            "#form",
            "**here_is_the_sensitive_info**"
          )
          .then(() => {
            resetForm({});
          })
          .catch(() => {
            const acknowledgement = document.createElement("H6");
            acknowledgement.innerHTML = "Something went wrong, please try.";
            document.getElementById("form").appendChild(acknowledgement);
          });
```

Answer (score 6):

In this case, EmailJS is meant to be used in the browser, so I don't think that the `userId` is sensitive at all.

In [their own documentation](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/installation/#browser-script), you can see the following instruction to get started.

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"
>   src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emailjs-com@2.4.1/dist/email.min.js">
> </script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>    (function(){
>       emailjs.init("YOUR_USER_ID");
>    })();
> </script>
> ```

That said, anyone can definitely see this in the source of the page in their browser. You are right to be cautious with anything sensitive in client-side JavaScript.

To avoid anyone using your `userId` on their own website (which is very unlikely since it only triggers emails that you configured), you can [whitelist your own domain](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/faq/does-emailjs-expose-my-account-to-spam/) *with their paid plan apparently*.

---

The [`.env` file, when used in a frontend project](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), only serves to set environment variables that are used at compilation time. The file never gets to the browser, but the values are often just interpolated (e.g. with the [*DefinePlugin*](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)) in the final bundle source, so there's nothing necessarily more secure here.

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your
> React app!
>
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can
> view them by inspecting your app's files.

```
# (s) for sensitive info

.env -> compilation -> bundle -> browser -> third-party
 (s)        (s)         (s)        (s)          (s)
```

That said, when used in a Node.js server, the `.env` file serves to set, again, environment variables, but this time, at the start of the application. These values are not shared with the frontend though, so one way to use this as a secure solution is to expose your own endpoint, whitelisting only your own domain, which then uses the sensitive information only on the server.

```
.env -> Node.js server -> third-party
 (s)          (s)            (s)      
                  ^
                 /  (api call)
...bundle -> broswer
```

*But then again, here, EmailJS' `userId` is not sensitive information.*

Answer (score 1):

You should never have sensitive info in the frontend. You should have for instance, a nodejs instance running, expose and endpoint, to the frontend, and call it. Then, inside your nodejs application, you should have a .env file with your credentials.

Then, just use the .env info from your node.js server.
If you have sensitive info in the frontend, you are exposing everything.

Comment: Also, trying to prevent your users from inspecting your code will never work. They can just download the JavaScript file without a browser and they have your credentials.

Comment: @101arrowz I will be using shopify as my back end and would not like to have a node.js backend as well. The userID is an ID for the email forwarding service I set up for form submission, so I guess it isn't all that sensitive since there is no password it isn't that much of a security risk? Also, how is using a .env any different? Wouldn't is ultimately contain the sensitive info which could also be sniffed?

Comment: Well, the idea is you don't serve the `.env` file to the clients. If the userID is not sensitive information, then what you're doing is totally fine.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the `userId` is in the `.env` if in the end, the _DefinePlugin_ just replaces it in the final bundle that's downloaded by the browser.

Comment: Well of course, the suggestion was to use a Node.js emailing client instead of EmailJS. Unless I interpreted this answer incorrectly? I think I did.

Comment: Yeah you're right about Node instead of client-side. It can be confusing though since most frontend projects bootstrapping provide a `.env` (like CRA) which is used in the client-side bundle.

Comment: @101arrowz I know this is getting slightly off topic now but could you provide an example of how exactly to use the .env file in the front end which we would retrieve from the Node server? I am just having trouble trying to understand how in our code if the user can access all of it they would not also be able to see the .env if we are accessing the variables in the file?

Comment: @pzero1 I've added clarification about `.env` in my answer since it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2023, the term `publicKey` is now used instead of `userId`:

```js
emailjs.send(serviceID, templateID, templateParams, publicKey);
```

EmailJS have addressed your concern in their FAQ:

> ## Is it okay to expose my Public Key?
>
> Indeed, someone could copy your keys (a well-known issue of any public API), but they will only be able to send your templates with your content, and they will not be able to send a custom email with their content (spam), which is not interesting for spammers. A better way to think of EmailJS in terms of security is not as a service that allows you to send emails from your code, but rather as a service that allows you to create a predefined set of emails via the dashboard, and then just trigger the emails from the code. This is quite similar to how emails are usually sent via a proprietary server code and how products like Intercom or customer.io are working.
>
> Reference: [EmailJS FAQ](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/faq/is-it-okay-to-expose-my-public-key/)

To answer your first question, **it is fine** to expose your public key.

> Also, is there a way for me to check if a user can somehow see this information my inspecting and finding the code in the method somehow?

All users can inspect your code (for example using Developer tools) and look for the public key. For a client to render your website in their browser, you need to send all your code (HTML+CSS+JS) to the client.

Answer (score -2):

1.first we need install DotENV in you are project

command: npm install dotenv

and now check in your package.json file install or not , if install file we can see like this **"dotenv": "^10.0.0",** and we can configure the file in your file in top of the file like "require('dotenv').config();" and now where you want now your using .env file.

first we need to understand how to using .env file in your file
any .env file are using (process.env)

and more information for Sensitive info Questions please go to the like
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17UVejOw3zA

Thankyou,

Comment: I don't see how dotenv files are relevant here at all.